# Java plugin is not recognized by firefox

Tags: java, firefox

I have installed jre7 and jdk 7 on a windows server multiple times.
I have configured java home and jre home variables.
Java for browsers is set in the control panel.
However, java plug-in is nowhere in firefox add on's , and acts like java is not installed : you need java plug in to run this applet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Firefox are you using, 32 or 64 bits? The new version of Firefox for Windows, 64 bits, does not recognize the Java Plugin, see it in :

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-java-plugin-to-view-interactive-content

Firefox 32 bits recognizes the Java Plugin.